# Failed: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, protractor

We have been using `protractor.promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])` extensively to resolve multiple promises up until the upgrade to [Protractor 4.0.0](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#400).

Now, it is failing with:

> Failed: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined

What should we use instead of `protractor.promise.all()`, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In version 4.0.0, the function `protractor.promise.all` is no longer present in the `protractor.promise` namespace:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/lib/ptor.ts

It is just a shortcut to the promise namespace from the Selenium library. So as an alternative:

```
var promise = require('selenium-webdriver').promise;

promise.all([promise1, promise2, promise3])
```