# Protractor error message returns a Object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protractor

I am expecting that the value_key (translation) is found by protractor and returns true, so that the test succeeds.

In my test-spec.js file I

```
it('test if tile "Value of Key" shows result text', function() {
   expect(
     element(by.xpath('//*[@id="idname"]/div/h3')
   ).getText()).toEqual(helpers.translate('value_key'));
});
```

Protractor error
Message:
Expected 'Value of Key' to equal Object({ $$state: Object({ status: 0 }), catch: Object({  }), then: Object({  }), finally: Object({  }) }).

Thank you for your help

Comment: helpers.translate('value_key') what it will return, Can i see the code for it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `helpers.translate()` function *returns a promise*.

In Protractor/Jasmine, only the left part of the assertion - the `expect()` part is capable of resolving promises implicitly. The right part, `toEqual()` in your case, is not.

Resolve the promise *explicitly*:

```
helpers.translate('value_key').then(function(value) {
    var text = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="idname"]/div/h3')).getText();
    expect(text).toEqual(value);
});
```

---

You can also use `protractor.promise.all()` to resolve both promises and then assert:

```
var promise1 = element(by.xpath('//*[@id="idname"]/div/h3')).getText();
var promise2 = helpers.translate('value_key');

protractor.promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(function(values) {
   expect(values[0]).toEqual(values[1]);
});
```

Not that there are currently [issues with using `protractor.promise.all()` in 4.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381292/failed-cannot-read-property-all-of-undefined) (should be [fixed in the next version(s)](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3367)). Workaround is available here.